# Angular application on Google Cloud: Bootstrap 4 btn doesn't fit in input-group-btn

Tags: angular, webpack, google-cloud-platform, bootstrap-4

I have an Angular 4 application with a search bar and a button with this code:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<input #searchBox (keyup)="..." [value]='...' id="lgFormGroupInput"
  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ..." aria-label="....">
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button (click)="..."
    class="btn btn-light search-bar-button" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</span></div>
```

Locally the search-bar-button looks fine:

[image]

But after I push the code to Google Cloud the button doesn't look the same:

[image]

I even tried the production mode locally but the button looks fine, so I can't figure out what could be the problem. I can only suspect there is a problem with the cloud build. I think noticed this problem after a build error on cloud and I solved that error by changing the `angular/cli` to `@angular/cli": "1.7.0-beta.1`. Any other higher or lower cli version gives me an error when pushing the changes to Google Cloud.

The Google Cloud logs looks fine except those:

[image]

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "something.org",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/something": "0.0.30",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "1.12.9",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/something": "0.0.30",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.19",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.7.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.4"
  }
}
```

**Update:**

1. The computed css for the good looking button(locally):
   [image]
2. The computed css for the bad looking button(production):
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is rather simple:

Add the `btn-lg` class to your button. That's it. Job done!

*But check further down below for more options...*

**Important:** Make sure that instead of loading "Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta" you **load the release version of Bootstrap 4** because the *beta version is outdated* and is known to break things here and there.

Working code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   
<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <input #searchBox (keyup)="..." [value]='...' id="lgFormGroupInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ..." aria-label="....">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button (click)="..." class="btn btn-lg btn-light search-bar-button" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, if you wanted to make the whole thing look **"perfect perfect"**, then you'd need to add the `input-group-append` class additionally to `input-group-btn`. That will truly "merge" the button with the input.

And if you aren't 100% happy with that look, you still have options.

Either remove `btn-light` from the `search-bar-button` OR add the class `btn-outline-secondary` to that.

Here are all 4 options to visually compare to each other:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <input #searchBox (keyup)="..." [value]='...' id="lgFormGroupInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search 4 ..." aria-label="....">
                <span class="input-group-append input-group-btn">
                    <button (click)="..." class="btn btn-lg btn-light btn-outline-secondary search-bar-button" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <input #searchBox (keyup)="..." [value]='...' id="lgFormGroupInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search 3 ..." aria-label="....">
                <span class="input-group-append input-group-btn">
                    <button (click)="..." class="btn btn-lg search-bar-button" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <input #searchBox (keyup)="..." [value]='...' id="lgFormGroupInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search 2 ..." aria-label="....">
                <span class="input-group-append input-group-btn">
                    <button (click)="..." class="btn btn-lg btn-light search-bar-button" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <input #searchBox (keyup)="..." [value]='...' id="lgFormGroupInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ..." aria-label="....">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button (click)="..." class="btn btn-lg btn-light search-bar-button" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just added a second code snippet. Compare all 4 options directly there...

Comment: **Also important:** Make sure that instead of loading "Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta" you **load the release version of Bootstrap 4** because the *beta version is outdated* and is known to break things here and there.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your answer and it works great. But a question still remains: How is it possible for the button to look good locally without all these changes?

Comment: Well, it's either a browser caching issue or one of the local files must be different than it is online. I don't think there is any other option possible. After all, the relevant output is just HTML and css in this case. Once you ensure that it's absolutely NOT a browser caching issue, then you have to look which file (or linked CDN) is different online. There must be a difference.

Comment: It does strike me as odd that you are loading both `bootstrap` AND `ngx-bootstrap` and while I haven't got much clue in regards to Angular, I don't think it's a good idea to load both of those things. I'd say there's a 99% chance that you should NOT load both of those things but rather pick one. But as I'm typing this I don't know enough about `ngx-bootstrap` to be able to tell anything. Whether or not this has anything to do with your issue, I don't know. So, I'd treat this comment as a small tip. No more.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the error about fs-events. Here are some ideas

1. When you run production mode locally, make sure your cache is cleared and/or disabled in DevTools.
2. Are there any console errors about failing to load images or scripts or anything when running on Google Cloud? Maybe something is failing to load there, but is working locally.
3. Inspect the styles applied to the elements in question and compare between local running production and what's running on Google Cloud. Not the differences and report back, maybe it will help narrow down the problem

Comment: I followed steps 1 and 2, cache is cleared and there are no console errors. For the 3 the computed css is slightly different between them and I already knew that. My question is why and how can this happen? Would it help to see the css for both?

Comment: Right, I'm hoping the computed CSS would lead to a clue as to what is different. Maybe if you send URL to it running in cloud and can tell me what you *expect* it to look like (computed values) I can get (assuming the source isn't public, because that would be the easiest)

Comment: I can't give you the url or the source but I updated my question with screenshots for locally and production computed css.